# Cutting out beam pockets

Tags: concrete, walls, foundation

Guys that were pouring concrete did not form beam pockets so now i have straight walls with no beam pockets. How can I possibly cut the beam pockets out now? I believe the size is 8 1/2 by 12 1/2.

Comment: use a saw that is large enough to cut through the concrete wall

Comment: Rather than cutting the foundation beam, would it work to pour pockets on the inside of the foundation beam and bond them to the beam by drilling holes for heavy rebar? What about heavy steel beam hangers attached to the inside of the concrete foundation beam?

Comment: Did the design have the pockets? If so, get the concrete contractor back to fix their mistake.